# Dart What are the concrete classes which are used to extend or implement the build-in types in dart e.g Float32List, Int32List, Uint8List etc

Tags: dart

I want to use a typed list in dart that can be one of the following types

```dart
/// The array  is typed array it can be :
/// - Float64List
/// - Float32List
/// - Int32List
/// - Uint32List
/// - Int16List
/// - Uint16List
/// - Uint8ClampedList
/// - Uint8List
/// - Int8List
///
/// and can be the object positions, colors, normals or uvs or indices
dynamic array;
```

I will like to have something like this

```dart
TypedArray array;
```

For now I use dynamic but I want to use an abstract class that hass all the properties of the typed lists.

How I can do that thank you all.

An example of what I am trying to do

```dart
class BufferAttribute {
  /// The array  is typed array it can be :
  /// - Float64List
  /// - Float32List
  /// - Int32List
  /// - Uint32List
  /// - Int16List
  /// - Uint16List
  /// - Uint8ClampedList
  /// - Uint8List
  /// - Int8List
  ///
  /// and can be the object positions, colors, normals or uvs or indices
  TypedData array;

  /// 1,2 or 3 components per iteration
  int itemSize;
  bool normalized;

  /// the number of elements in the array.
  /// how is computed: array.length / numbe of components.
  int count = 0;

  /// gl.STATIC_DRAW
  int usage = 35044;

  BufferAttribute(this.array, this.itemSize, [this.normalized = false]) {
    count = array.length ~/ itemSize; <---- I get an Error
    usage = 35044; // gl.STATIC_DRAW
  }
}

The error says: 
The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'TypedData'.
Try importing the library that defines 'length', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'.dartundefined_getter
```

Comment: Your question title asks for concrete classes, but your actual question seems to be asking for an abstract base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be [`TypedData`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-typed_data/TypedData-class.html):

```dart
TypedData array = UInt8List(...);
```

Know, however, that the base type `TypedData` doesn't expose many members, only the properties `buffer`, `elementSizeInBytes`, `lengthInBytes`, and `offsetInBytes`. I don't know how useful that will be, and depending on your purposes might be an overkill amount of abstraction.

Comment: Hi @Abion47 thank you for the answer but If I change the type to TypedData and then try to access the length of the array I can't any suggestion for this?? I will update the example also

Comment: @GeorgeC. The `length` property is from `List`, and `List` and `TypedData` are two different unrelated interfaces. You could try to calculate it with `length = lengthInBytes / elementSizeInBytes`, but the fact that you are trying to use the typed data like a list might be the first indication that you aren't using the right type for your purposes.

Comment: thank you,  you are the best

Comment: @GeorgeC. I'm looking at your updated example, and I think that a simple `ByteBuffer` would be fully sufficient for your needs. Any typed list can be converted in to a `ByteBuffer` via the `buffer` property.